# jQuery: correct syntax for ':not()'

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to filter a list of elements via ':not()', and jQuery seems to be ignoring my filter.

here is the code:

```
myElements.filter(':not(.someclass)');
```

jquery still selects all of myElements...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myElements = myElements.filter(":not(.someClass)");
myElements.hide();
```

or:

```
myElements = myElements.not(".someClass");
myElements.hide();
```

You will actually need to assign the filtered collection to a variable to capture the modified (filtered) collection, otherwise you are effectively just referencing `myElements` in its initial state. If you don't want to do that, you can always use chaining, for example:

```
myElements.filter(":not(.someClass)")
          .hide();
```